# The ui-tabs not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I used ui-tabs ,this is the code iam used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs({ event: '' });
  });

  function validateContact() {
    var fname = $('#first_name1').val();

    if (fname == '') {
      alert("Enter Name");
    } else {
      $('#tabs').tabs({ event: 'click' });
      doitcontact();
    }
  }

  function doitcontact() {
    var cnt = $("#frmdocontact").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "doitcontact.php",
      data: cnt,

      success: function (msg) {
        var spt = msg.split('#$@$');
        //alert(spt);

        $('#hid_uid').val(spt[0]);
        $('#custom').val(spt[0]);

        $('#hid_add_vehicle').val(spt[0]);
        $('#hid_saleid').val(spt[1]);

        var valreturn = $("#return").val();

        if (valreturn) {
          valreturn = valreturn + "?cntdoit=" + spt[0];
          $("#return").val(valreturn);
        }

        //alert(msg);
        //console.log(contactSent);
        var pkg = $('input:radio[name=pkg]:checked').val();

        var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $tabs.tabs('select', selected + 1);
        //window.location="thankyou.php"
      }
    });

  }
</script>

<ul>
  <li id="tabVInfo"><a href="#tabs-2">Contact Information</a></li>
  <li id="tabVCond"><a href="#tabs-3">Vehicle Information</a></li>
  <li id="tabVPhoto"><a href="#tabs-4">Additional Vehicle Information</a></li>
  <li id="tabVCheck"><a href="#tabs-5">Check Out</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-2">
  <form id="frmdocontact" name="frmdocontact" method="post">
    <input id="first_name1" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />
    <input type="button" id="sub" name="sub" value="Next >>" class="next-product" onclick="validateContact();" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="tabs-">hhhhhhhhh</div>
<div id="tabs-4">kkkkkkkk</div>
<div id="tabs-5">llllllllll</div>
```

I want to remove the clicked event when the page is loaded.That is working correctly.
Then i have to be able to click on tabs if already filled out data.  so if i filled out page 1 and 2 and am on 3 then they should be able to click on the 1 or 2 tab and it should have the already entered data in it.

Here page 1 and 2 means divs.In my code when i load the page the tabs are not clickable.Then i enter datas into page 1 and click on nex button then it goes to 2nd page and all tabs are now clickable.

But i actually need to page 1 tabs pnly shoud be clickable.

How can i do this?

Can anyone have solve it?

if there is any solution for that?.............

Give a solution ASAP...........

Comment: @rahul i dont know how make a js fiddle...

Comment: jsfiddle.net , put your code there, it helps us undertsand your problem

Comment: @Christian but i dont know how to include the js and css files in jsfiddle....

Comment: You could isolate the problem by giving fake data... create a test which shows the problem. But I put an answer here, I don't know if it will help, but worth a shot :-)

Comment: @rahul this is the jsfiddle but the onlcick not working,i dont knw how to setup it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the {event: ''} inside your tabs calling to enable all clicks. Then you change the HREF of the tab you want to disable. In this example I have disabled the check out tab.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#tabVCheck > a").attr("href", "#");
```

you can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nKsZF/28/

Comment: Okay, then I recommend you create a test with fake data in jsFiddle. It is important that we get a clear image of your needs to help you.

Comment: i cant to include jquery1.7.1 in jsfiddle. how can i load that?

Comment: @Chrisian look this fiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/hpU3T/1/` here i edit with my code then i can see my code with correct design.

Comment: @Christain so i login in my fiddle account and try to create the same one with my code in account,but i can to load the `Jquery 1.7.1` from left side drop down...Why?or how can i load this?

Comment: this is the fiddel i created but design breaked `http://jsfiddle.net/mariya/T9KKT/16/`

Comment: the above link is now corrected with design look at the above fiddle link, but its onclick not working....

Comment: I will have a look later today :-)

Comment: yes now there have test code in fiddle without any error,you can check it `http://jsfiddle.net/mariya/nKsZF/24/`

Comment: @Chrisian there is a model of my code in jsfiddle ,i removed the function `doitcontact()` because it is an ajax function ,i think that is not an issue here so i removed.So plz check my code jsfiddle.......

Comment: Okay, answer is updated. I just removed the event property from the object you sent as an argument to the tabs method.

This is what you want?

Comment: but there have a problem,first enter values to text box ,then click on next but button ,then it goes to the `Vehicle` tab ,then i click on the `Contact` tab,then click on the same `Next` button,then the last two tabs have a color change ,plz try to check that in my new code....

Comment: @Chrisian i also edited my jsfiddle code now check this jsfiddle.net/mariya/nKsZF/50.